# rails render view onclick with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a view, where users can click on different buttons and render different content based on the buttons they click. I've tried getting this done with JS but can't really get it to work. I made a button in my view:

```
<div class="link">
  <%= link_to "Greetings", "#" %>
</div>
<div id="show"></div>
```

then in job.js.erb:

```
$(function() {
  $('.link').click(function() {
    $('#show').append("<%=escape_javascript render(:partial => 'show' %>");
  });
});
```

unfortunately render is not supported in assets, but I don't really know what the best way is to make this happen.

Comment: Well, if you using assets, you shouldn't be mixing javascript and rails. What about ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can try is to let the button click go to a controller action, by AJAX, and then render the file with name `<action_name>.js.erb`. this file will then be able to call the `render` action.

I will expatiate more with the following:

Assuming the resource in question is `Greetings` and you have a `dynamic_show` action in the `Greetings` controller, for example, and you have a `dynamic_show_greetings_path` routing to this action.

From inside your view, you can have:

```
<div class="link">
  <%= link_to "Greetings", dynamic_show_greetings_path, remote: true %>
</div>
<div id="show"></div>
```

and the `Greetings#dynamic_show` action will be like follow:

```
def dynamic_show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

then, in your view directory, you have a `dynamic_show.js.erb` file, which will contain the script to append the dynamic view as follow:

```
$('#show').html("<%=escape_javascript render(:partial => 'show') %>");
```

And that solves it for you!

Of course, to now make it dynamic, you have to then pass in params to the controller, and then render content based on the response gotten.

PS:

- setting `remote: true` on the link ensures that the call will be an `AJAX` call.
- controller actions by default renders the file with same name as the action name, therefore, `dynamic_show` responding to `js` will render `dynamic_show.js.erb`

Hope this throws a great light into it for you... ;)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need jQuery for this.

You can wrap the rendered partial in a parent div with a hide class. When the button is clicked toggle displaying the content.

http://api.jquery.com/show/

```
$('#your-button').click(function(e){
    $('.hidden-div').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.

Firstly, if you're wanting to load the JS ***on-page***, you need to use what `@anchalee` suggested, and preload the content with some sort of "hide" class in the CSS:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", "a.hidden", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   el = $(this).attr("href");
   $(el).toggle();
});

#app/views/controller/your_view.html.erb
<%= link_to "User", "#user", class: "hidden" %>
<div id="user" class="hidden">
    Hello
</div>
```

This will take any divs with the `id` specified by the `href` attribute of the link, and then make it so that the `div` will `hide` or `show` depending on its current state.

--

Secondly, you have the ***off-page*** method (using `ajax`).

This is used to get data from the server, and will be where you'd load server-centric data such as what you're trying to do now.

Doing this is actually quite simple:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
class YourController < ApplicationController
   layout: Proc.new{|c| !c.request.xhr? }
end
```

This will return any data you need without the `layout`:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", "#show", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.get($(this).attr("href"), function(data){
      $("#show").html(data);
   });
});

#app/views/your_controller/show.html.erb
<%= link_to "Show", [[url for page]], id: "show" %>
```

Comment: The second method seems to be what I want since I need to load a lot of different pages so preloading and hiding them is not the way to go. But I get an error on the controller layout part (unexpected ':'). Could you explain this a bit more? I don't really understand what is is you'r doing there.