# Like/Unlike button

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to create like button which, allows a user to like a post. Then button transform into an unlike button which, allows a user to unlike a post. I did it, but i think it's wrong.

My code

```
    <div class='likes'>
       <% if user_signed_in?%>
          <% unless current_user.likes?(post) %>
             <%= link_to image_tag('unlike.png', alt: 'unlike'), like_path(post) %>
          <% else %>
             <%= link_to image_tag('like.png', alt: 'like'), unlike_path(post) %>
          <% end %>
          <% if post.likers_count >0 %>
             <%= post.likers_count %>
          <% end %>
       <% end %>
    </div>
```

When I click on like button whole page is reloaded, but i need only reload  a button. How I can do it?

Comment: With some javascript. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: I read this article and I don't understand how to do it. Can you give me an exemple because I'm not very good in js.

Comment: If you want to prevent reloading the whole page, Try using ajax to post `remote: true`

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33468554/4330954)  for example on how to implement. Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :posts do
   match :vote, on: :member, via: [:post, :delete]
end

#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def vote
      @post = Post.find params[:id]
      if request.post?
         ... vote up
      elsif request.delete?
         ... vote down
      end
      respond_to do |format|
         format.js #-> only XHR allowed
      end
   end
end

#app/views/posts/vote.js.erb
$(".likes").html("<%=j render 'posts/vote' %>");

#app/views/posts/_vote.html.erb
<% if user_signed_in?%>
    <% method = current_user.likes?(@post) ? ["post", ""] : ["delete", "un"] %>
    <%= link_to image_tag("#{method[1]}like.png", alt: "#{method[1]}like"), post_vote_path(@post), method: method[0].to_sym, remote: true %>
    <%= @post.likers_count if @post.likers_count > 0 %>
<% end %>
```

In your `posts#show` view, you should do this:

```
#app/views/posts/show.html.erb
<div class="likes">
   <%= render partial: "vote" %>
</div>
```

Comment: I get an error undefined method `post_vote_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f0c61fc0a20>:0x007f0c61fb3de8>

Comment: What does `rake routes` output?

Comment: vote_post POST|DELETE /posts/:id/vote(.:format)                   posts#vote

Comment: undefined method `request' for #<Class:0x007fefc989bf78>

Comment: in line @post = Post.request

Comment: Shit that was my bad sorry - let me fix

Comment: You should open a chat (if possible) to prevent such a long list of conversational comments.

Comment: Added `remote: true` to links, this should fix it

Comment: All is work, but likers_count changes only after reload whole page

Comment: Really? So your code updates and then the `likers_count` stays the same even though we updated the `@post` object?