# keep rails params using ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have `/map/mappge` page already got @name from my index. So my map controller,

```
class MapController < ApplicationController
  def mappage
    @name = params[:name]
  end
```

and, I send it by submit tag.

```
<form action="/map/mappage" method="GET">
   <%= select_tag "univ", "<option selected>selected</option><option value='name1'>name1</option><option value='name2'>name2</option><option value='name3'>name3</option>".html_safe, class:"btn btn-default btn-hg dropdown-toggle" %>
   <%= submit_tag "go", class:"btn btn-success btn-hg" %>
</form>
```

like this.
When I select `name1` and submit it, the mappage url looks like

```
'myhost'/map/mappage?name=name1&commit=go
```

What I want to do is call ajax while I keep the name parameters.
So I call

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#my_button").click(function () {
        var ajax_name = "<%= @name %>";

        $.ajax({
            url: "/map/mappage",
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                'name': ajax_name
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("good");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

When I click `"#my_button"`, alert message comes. The thing is, when I click `"#my_button"`, error comes out. `@name` is nil. And I checked that my url looks like

`'myhost'/map/mappage?#`

How can I keep @name parameters? Any suggestions, or document that I can read?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery

Comment: I don't think that you're actually using params[:name] to get name value as this is clear that you're using select statement , so please make your question clear

Comment: @Van Huy, Thank you for your link. I solved it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `rails way` to do this would be to have a form with `remote: true`, and an endpoint for it (a controller with `respond_to :js`, and a corresponding `.js` view).

Pls, let me know if you need this illustrated with some code.

Comment: bosskovic is right. setting remote true, and passing your params straight is a great way to achieve what you trying to do. [Check this SO answer on how to do this.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33468554/4330954)

Answer (score 0):

You can use gem ' [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon)
It seem to be easy way to pass params from controller rails into javascript file via view